# Django How can I solve NoReverseMatch error?

Tags: python, django, get

I'm making the website using Django.

I have a problem for url.

I tried to access the website, but an error occurred.

Error is NoReverseMatch.

**Reverse for 'add' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['purchase/order/(?P<CAT_ID>[^/]+)/$']**

How can I solve this problem?

```py
# urls.py
{% for value in object_list %}

    <tr>
      <form action="{% url 'purchase_order:add' value.CAT_ID %}" method="get">
         <td scope="row">{{ value.CAT_ID }}</td>
         <td scope="row">{{ value.INFOR }}</td>
         <td scope="row">
            <input type="submit" value="CREATE" class="btn btn-outline-secondary btn-sm">
         </td>
       </form>
    </tr>

{% endfor %}
```

```py
# urls.py

app_name = 'purchase_order'

urlpatterns = [

    # CREATE URL
    path('order/<str:CAT_ID>/', views.Order_add_View.as_view(), name='add'),
    
    ]
```

```py
# views.py

class Order_add_View(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Purchase_Request
    # template_name = 'purchase_order/add.html'
    fields = ['CAT_ID', INFOR]

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

        CAT_ID = self.kwargs['CAT_ID']

        return render(request, 'purchase_order/add.html', {'CAT_ID':CAT_ID})

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.owner = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we look at your form action url that django is trying to parse but cannot

```
{% url 'purchase_order:add' value.CAT_ID %}
```

The error says `Reverse for 'add' with no arguments not found`.. but you've given it an argument! `value.CAT_ID` so what gives?

What this means is that no value exists in `value.CAT_ID` in the template's context. The url might as well just read

```
{% url 'purchase_order:add' %}
```

because that is what django is seeing at runtime.

You've iterated through your `object_list` with

```
{% for value in object_list %}
```

As such, `object_list` isn't the views context but merely a list of serialised `Purchase_Request` objects that your class based view has added to the templates context for you (if setup correctly). Your `Purchase_Request` model doesn't have a `CAT_ID` field hence `value.CAT_ID` returns nothing.

You did add `CAT_ID` to the template's context though

```py
return render(request, 'purchase_order/add.html', {'CAT_ID':CAT_ID})
```

It is simply just `CAT_ID` in the template context.

```html
{% for value in object_list %}

    <tr>
      <form action="{% url 'purchase_order:add' CAT_ID %}" method="get">
         <td scope="row">{{ CAT_ID }}</td>
         <td scope="row">{{ value.INFOR }}</td>
         <td scope="row">
            <input type="submit" value="CREATE" class="btn btn-outline-secondary btn-sm">
         </td>
       </form>
    </tr>

{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. When click the button,  I wanna take the "CAT_ID" on the next page like "purchase/order/CAT1". And object_list is called from another model not purchase request.   

When I return HttpResponse, It is working. like this return HttpResponse(CAT_ID) but "render(request, 'route.html', {'CAT_ID':CAT_ID}" is not working..

Answer (score 0):

You need to add input the CAT_ID as a keyword arg to the template tag:

```
{% for value in object_list %}

    <tr>
      <form action="{% url 'purchase_order:add' CAT_ID=value.CAT_ID %}" method="get">
         <td scope="row">{{ value.CAT_ID }}</td>
         <td scope="row">{{ value.INFOR }}</td>
         <td scope="row">
            <input type="submit" value="CREATE" class="btn btn-outline-secondary btn-sm">
         </td>
       </form>
    </tr>

{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. But It is not working ...

It has same error below.

django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'add' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['purchase/order/(?P<CAT_ID>[^/]+)/$']

Comment: oh, then forget it. Maybe this can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13938700/14999453

Comment: Still not working.. :(   

When I return HttpResponse, It is working.  

like this   

return HttpResponse(CAT_ID)

but "render(request, 'route.html', {'CAT_ID':CAT_ID}" is not working